# PHP How to check if a subclass has overridden a method of a superclass?

Tags: php, reflection

Using PHP, how can a class determine if a subclass has overridden one if its methods?

Given the following two classes:

```
class Superclass {
    protected function doFoo($data) {
        // empty
    }

    protected function doBar($data) {
        // empty
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    protected function doFoo($data) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can a method be added to Superclass that will perform different actions depending on which of its methods have been overridden?

For example:

```
if ([doFoo is overridden]) {
    // Perform an action without calling doFoo
}
if ([doBar is overridden]) {
    // Perform an action without calling doBar
}
```

Comment: @schleis The example was a bit contrived. Right now I have to expose some information over HTTP which can be pulled from the structure of existing classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [`ReflectionMethod::getPrototype`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getprototype.php) .

```
$foo = new \ReflectionMethod('Subclass', 'doFoo');

$declaringClass = $foo->getDeclaringClass()->getName();
$proto = $foo->getPrototype();

if($proto && $proto->getDeclaringClass()->getName() !== $declaringClass){ 
  // overridden
}
```

If the classes match, it wasn't overridden, otherwise it was.

---

Or if you know both class names, simply compare `$declaringClass` against the other class name.